# Changing WooCommerce buy button link?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I already have set up my WooCommerce child theme and organized the website with dummy data.

I can't find a way to change the link from the "Add to Cart" to an external link.
I want it so that each time someone clicks on the "Add to Cart" button the user be taken to external link example.com

How do I go about this?

P.S: I'm not worried about any of the security aspects since the site won't be used for real money transactions.

Comment: Are you using wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not going to ask about the idea behind your question, but using this filter will for sure do what you need:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'change_add_product_link' );
function change_add_product_link( $link ) {
    global $product;
    $product_id = $product->id;
    $product_sku = $product->get_sku();
    $link = '<a href="//www.yourtargeturl.com?id='.$product_id.'" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="'.$product_id.'" data-product_sku="'.$product_sku.'" data-quantity="1" class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_variable">'.sfws_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text().'</a>';
    return $link;
}
?>
```

Comment: What if I wanted to set up different links for different products?

Comment: I've updated the code above, you now sending the product id along to your target url so you can differentiate the product. If you need a more broad solution then you need to share some more insights

Comment: **Wonder where to put this?** You have two options: 1. (Recommended) - you author your own plugin, that contains this snippet, and any other customizations you'd like. This is very straightforward: wpbeaverbuilder.com/creating-wordpress-plugin-easier-think OR, option 2. Add it to your theme's `functions.php` file. Many people suggest adding to your theme, but it is FAR better to separate functionality customizations like this from your theme, so I would encourage you to write a simple plugin.

Answer (score 0):

**Woo-commerce** plugin for Wordpress have custom `add-to-cart` features. You can add it from `product` or using `shortcode` to your script or posts.

> Here is the details about  -

- [WooCommerce Custom “Add to Cart”](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-custom-add-cart-urls-ultimate-guide/)
- [Creating a custom “Add to Cart” URL](https://nicola.blog/2015/09/18/creating-custom-add-to-cart-url/)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the product type you use. You can find all add_to_cart template file in the folder.

```
woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/
```

You can set your product as external product, and it will redirect user to the external page.

If you want to stay with simple or variation product, you'll need to copy/paste the file you need in your child theme and modify it.